# Android volley change my response from JsonObjectRequest

Tags: android, json, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

I'm trying to make a standard JsonObjectRequest with the volley libary. Everything works well except the response from the request.

Here is how I'm doing the request:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("geoLong", location.getLongitude());
jsonObject.put("geoLat", location.getLatitude());

JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                    jsonObject.toString(), createResponseListener(), createErrorListener()); 
jsonRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(15000, 2, 1));

requestQueue.add(jsonRequest);
```

I expect the following json response:

```
{
"total": 79,
"results": [
{
  "id": "123",
  "title": "test",
  "distance": 3873.7552258171,
  "address": {
    "street": "Street",
    "zip": "12345",
    "city": "city",
    "country": "country",
  },
  "geo": {
    "longitude": x,
    "latitude": y
  }
}, 

...
...

]}
```

but from my Volley Request I get something like this:

```
{
"nameValuePairs": {
"total": 79,
"results": {
  "values": [{
  "nameValuePairs": {
    "id": 123, 
    "title": "test", 
    "distance": 3873.7552258171, 
    "address": {
      "nameValuePairs": {
        "street": "street", 
        "zip": "zip", 
        "city": "city", 
        "country": "country"
      }
    },
    "geo": {
      "nameValuePairs": {
        "longitude": x, 
        "latitude": y
      }
    }
  },

... 
...

}]}}
```

Does anyone know why the response is formatted like this and how can I change it to what I expect?

Comment: this must be issue in your webservices.

Comment: no it's not I used the postman chrome app to make the post request and there I get the correct json format. In the debug console in Android Studio I get the wrong format :/

Comment: This is issue with your webservices and not with Android code.

Comment: It can't be a webservice issu because if I do the request with HttpURLConnection in an asynctask the json response is correct (without the "nameValuePairs" attribute).

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that what you expected is wrong? I'm not saying the JSON formatting is correct, Just saying that Volley might have nothing to do with it, make sure every other method of testing isn't giving you a processed response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by myself. I send the JSON to the second activity as a String and I'm using

```
new Gson().toJson(response)
```

to change the JSONObject to a String and this changed the JSON format.
I don't know why this happend but it was the problem.

Comment: where in your question this was mentioned? you should probably add details as much as possible

Comment: I thought it was a problem with volley so I did not mentioned, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Use `HashMap` to send parameters in Post requests

```
HashMap<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("geoLong", location.getLongitude());
params.put("geoLat", location.getLatitude());
```

Then

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(url,
                    new JSONObject(params), createResponseListener(), createErrorListener());
```

For better understanding inspect this code snippet i used this when i was making post requests and i get response as i expect.

```
JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, new JSONObject(params),
       new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
               try {
                   VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(4));
               } catch (JSONException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
           @Override
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
           }
       });
```

Comment: Using a HashMap does not help, still getting these "nameValueParis" attributes in the json response.

Comment: You don't need to add ```Request.Method.POST``` in JsonObjectRequest. try removing it from parameters of JsonObjectRequest.